# Polymorphic return types and "rigid type variable" error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vector

There's a simple record `Column v a` which holds a `Vector` from the `Data.Vector` family (so that `v` can be `Vector.Unboxed`, just `Vector` etc), it's name and type (simple enum-like ADT `SupportedTypes`). I would like to be able to serialize it using the `binary` package. To do that, I try to define a `Binary` instance below.

Now `put` works fine, however when I try to define deserialization in the `get` function and want to set a specific type to the `rawVector` that is being returned based on the `colType` (`U.Vector Int64` when it's `PInt`, `U.Vector Double` when it's `PDouble` etc) - I get this error message:

> Couldn't match type `v` with `U.Vector`
>
> `v` is a rigid type variable bound by the instance declaration at `src/Quark/Base/Column.hs`:75:10
>
> Expected type: `v a`
>
> Actual type: `U.Vector Int64`

error.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal - deserialize `Vector`s of different types based on the `colType` value or am I stuck with defining `Binary` instance for all possible `Vector` / primitive type combinations? Shouldn't be the case...

Somewhat new to Haskell and appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TransformListComp, RankNTypes, 
            TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, OverloadedLists, DeriveGeneric  #-}

{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts,
         TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables, InstanceSigs #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

data Column v a = Column {rawVector :: G.Vector v a => v a, colName :: Text, colType :: SupportedTypes }

instance (G.Vector v a, Binary (v a)) => Binary (Column v a) where

  put Column {rawVector = vec, colName = cn, colType = ct} = do put (fromEnum ct) >> put cn >> put vec


  get = do t <- get :: Get Int
         nm <- get :: Get Text
         let pt = toEnum t :: SupportedTypes
         case pt of 
            PInt -> do vec <- get :: Get (U.Vector Int64)
                       return Column {rawVector = vec, colName = nm, colType = pt}
            PDouble -> do vec <- get :: Get (U.Vector Double)
                          return Column {rawVector = vec, colName = nm, colType = pt}
```

**UPDATED** Thank you for all the answers below, some pretty good ideas! It's quite clear that what I want to do is impossible to achieve head-on - so that is my answer. But the other suggested solutions are a good reading in itself, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Change `vec <- get :: Get (U.Vector Int64)` to `vec <- get` and let type inference figure it out. Same for `vec <- get :: Get (U.Vector Double)`. Of course the parsed vector will not be a vector of ints or doubles (it will be whatever the person using your function specifies) but this is not an issue with Binary - your data type does not represent what you think it does. You probably want [existential quantification](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type).

Comment: get without qualification either complains it cannot figure out the type or reads doubles as bytes etc as was noted below

Comment: Did more reading on existential datatypes and start to realize @user2407038 you are absolutely right. That seems to achieve exactly what I want - collection of differently typed vectors on which I can operate using generic vector interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are really trying to represent is

```
data Column v = Column (Either (v Int) (v Double))
```

but this representation may be unsatisfactory to you. So how do you write this type with the vector itself at the 'top level' of the constructor?

First, start with a representation of your sum (`Either Int Double`) at the type level, as opposed to the value level:

```
data IsSupportedType a where 
  TInt :: IsSupportedType Int 
  TDouble :: IsSupportedType Double
```

From here `Column` is actually quite simple:

```
data Column v a = Column (IsSupportedType a) (v a)
```

But you'll probably want `a` existentially quantified to use it how you want:

```
data Column v = forall a . Column (IsSupportedType a) (v a)
```

The binary instance is as follows:

```
instance (Binary (v Int), Binary (v Double)) => Binary (Column v) where
  put (Column t v) = do 
    case t of 
      TInt -> put (0 :: Int) >> put v 
      TDouble -> put (1 :: Int) >> put v 

  get = do 
    t :: Int <- get 
    case t of 
      0 -> Column TInt <$> get  
      1 -> Column TDouble <$> get
```

Note that there is no inherent reliance in `Vector` here - `v` could really be anything.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is it's not just Double or Int, it's a whole bunch of types, so all this quickly becomes tedious. Current solution that works for me is similar - data GenericColumn = CInt Vector Int | CDouble Vector Double | CWord Vector Word etc. I was just looking for less boilerplate and less packing / boxing of types into ADT.

Comment: If you really want to avoid boilerplate you can generalize this much further, but at some point it gets inordinately complex. This solution is nice and simple. The only boilerplate you really have to write is functions of type `Int -> Maybe (Exists IsSupportedType)` and `IsSupportedType a -> Int`. If you have some concrete example of boilerplate you would like to avoid, you'd probably be more likely to get an example that will be applicable to your actual use case.

Comment: I agree, it is nice - it's just it's about the same as the "GenericColumn" I cited above, although more elegant / generic. But Binary definition in GenCol approach looks pretty similar to yours:   `instance Binary GenericColumn where
    put (CInt v) =      do put (0 :: Word8) >> put v
    put (CDouble v) =   do put (1 :: Word8) >> put v
    put (CText v) =     do put (4 :: Word8) >> put v

    get = do t <- get :: Get Word8
             case t of
                0 -> get >>= return . CInt 
                1 -> get >>= return . CDouble
                4 -> get >>= return . CText`

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're actually running into (or if you're not yet, that you will) is that you're trying to decide a resulting type from an input value. You *cannot* do that. At all. You could cleverly lock the result type in a box and throw away the key so the type appears to be normal from the outside, but then you cannot do anything much with it because you *locked the type in a box and threw away the key*. You can store extra information about it using GADTs and boxing it up with a type class instance, but even still this is not a great idea.

Your could make your life far easier here if you simply had two constructors for Column to reflect whether there was a vector of `Int`s or `Double`s.

But really, don't do any of that. Just let the automatically derivable Binary instance deserialize any deserializable value into your vector for you.

```
data Column a = ... deriving (Binary)
```

Using the `DeriveAnyClass` extension that let's you derive any class that has a `Generic` implementation (which `Binary` has). Then just deserialize a `Column Double` or a `Column Int` when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - throwing away the key analogy is interesting. I thought I could still pattern match on rawVector but then there's no way to figure out "a" type. However, if I constrain it to Num for instance could still use a bunch of polymorphic functions on it - so still don't 100% understand why Haskell doesn't allow this.     ----- solution with Column = CInt Vector Int64 | CDouble Vector Double etc works and is the one I'm using currently, I was just thinking of it was possible to generalize more elegantly.

Comment: PS automatic deriving doesn't really work, tried that in many combinations, with and without generics

Comment: Haskell doesn't allow this because it can't. Not yet. Types are erased at run time. When you unbox something, you only get what you put into the box, which never includes the type. It _can_ include type class dictionaries. These are just values that the type checker knows you had to have (or more likely that the compiler has) put in correctly to make the box in the first place, so you can use them when you open the box elsewhere. The type itself is gone.

For automatic deriving, would `data Col v a = Col {raw :: v a, cName :: Text, ..} deriving (Binary)` suffice? You could constrain v later.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, you can simply not case on the type, and always call

```
vec <- get
return Column {rawVector = vec, colName = nm, colType = pt}
```

This fulfills your type signature properly. But note that `colType` is not useful to you here -- you have no way to enforce that it corresponds to the type within your vector, since it only exists at the value level. But that may be ok, and you may simply want to remove `colType` from your data structure altogether, since you can always derive it directly from the concrete type of `a` chosen in `Column v a`.

In fact, the constraint in the `Column` type isn't doing much good either, and I think it would be better to render it just as

```
data Column v a = Column {rawVector :: v a, colName :: Text}
```

Now you can just enforce the `G.Vector` constraint at call sites where necessary...

Comment: Yes, this would have been one pretty elegant option. Unfortunately, deserialization doesn't really work:  `No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v0 a0)
      arising from a use of ‘loadColumn’
    The type variables ‘v0’, ‘a0’ are ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector V.Vector a
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector’
      instance Data.Primitive.Types.Prim a =>
` -- etc

Comment: I bet it works if you specify a type signature of the expected result type at the callsite of loadColumn.

Comment: Ah, good point, need to type the "decode" call, right. Thanks @sclv, will think through this approach, it changes the flow somewhat but may be pretty versatile for what I want to achieve!